# How to create custom attribute that support all views in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

In Android, XML is used for designing User Interface. Android provide set of attributes for each tag [ex: id,layout_width, layout_height].

But Is there any possibility to add a new attribute for all the tags commonly in Android.

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/search_result"
    extra = "This is search field"
    useOfThisTag = "Search Operation"
    etc...
 />
```

Comment: To what end? You certainly can define your own custom attributes, but `TextView` isn't going to know what to do with them.

Comment: is there any possibility to add extra information other than android:tag

Comment: is there any possibility to achieve this using xmlns namespace

Comment: Yeah, your custom attributes would be in your app's namespace, so that would be acceptable in the layout XML. But, again, `TextView`, for example, isn't going to know what to do with them.

Comment: create a custom `TextView` then with your 2 new custom attributes

Comment: I used <tag> attribute inside view. This used to pass more string with key

Comment: Do note that `<tag>` only works on API 21+.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what would you like to achieve. There are no global attributes in the official Android implementation. The ones you mentioned are of two kinds:

1. View attributes: id, tag, background, padding, etc. These are interpreted by View class and seem to be global, because almost everything you see in xml layout files extends View.
2. Layout attributes: width, height, margin, etc. This group is always interpreted by a parent layout. If you place a view inside LinearLayout, for that view you can use attributes declared by LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

If you wish to add a truly global attribute, you can try Calligraphy's approach. It's a library which adds support for custom fonts to all text views. Their author uses a custom ContextWrapper and a resource parser to intercept Calligraphy's attributes while parsing view tags.

This is very similiar to how include, fragment, layout and merge tags work but on attribute level. These tags are global and are parsed and handled inside LayoutInflater.

Answer (score -1):

Create **attrs.xml** file for custom attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ColorOptionsView">
        <attr name="titleText" format="string" localization="suggested" />
        <attr name="valueColor" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml** : your layout that contains textview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
<!-- define new name space for your attributes -->
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- Assume that this is your new component. It uses your new attributes -->
        <com.example.vishva.CustomTextview
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            custom:titleText="Background color"
            custom:valueColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
             />

</LinearLayout>
```

you also have to create CustomTextview Class that extends Textview class